# How can i make the value the the user inputs appear next to thew print statement?

Tags: java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nameP{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

    int value;

    System.out.println("Type a number: ");
    value = user.nextInt();

    if (value % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("even");
    else
        System.out.println("odd");
    }
}
```

Need help making the value given by the user appear right next to the print statement....and not in the bottom as it commonly happens. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which print statement are you talking about? There's three. And I'm not sure which you are referring too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.out.print`

instead of `System.out.println`

println prints a newline after the String you send it.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("The number " + value + " is even");